# Runtime sorting of data in microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access

I have an access report which fetches data from an underlying access query. The problem I am having is that I want to be able to allow the user the ability to sort the data based on 3 separate fields. How can I give the user this facility that he can choose if he wants to sort the incoming data based on a field A, B or C?

Kindly help. 
Thanks!

Comment: I am still not sure how to go about it. By the limited knowledge I have, I am not sure if its possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should help.

First, use *openArgs* parameter to pass user's selected OrderBy field:

```
DoCmd.Close acReport, "MyReport"
DoCmd.OpenReport "MyReport", acViewPreview, , , , "OrderByColumnName"
```

Then, use passed value for ordering on report Load:

For Access 2007+:

```
Private Sub Report_Load()
    Me.Report.OrderByOn = True
    Me.Report.OrderBy = Me.Report.OpenArgs
End Sub
```

For Access 2003:

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Me.Report.OrderByOn = True
    Me.Report.OrderBy = Me.Report.OpenArgs
End Sub
```

The outcome is the same: report will be [re]sorted based on the passed parameters.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I would try and let let you know if this works in my case. Thanks :)

Comment: There is no OnLoad event in reports -- I think you mean OnOpen.

Comment: BTW, I'd never use the Filter/Sort properties of reports in the OnOpen event. If I'm writing code in that event, I'm going to alter the report's Recordsource or it's Sorting/Grouping definitions.

Comment: @David: You must be kidding :). I DID mean On Load event. And THERE IS On Load event for Forms/Reports. Moreover, before I posted the code, I tested it. It works just fine. The only issue here can be if Farax did mean something else or I did not get (exactly) what he wanted.

Comment: OK, I haven't started using A2007/A2010 for development, so I was only looking at A2003. The original question doesn't say what version of Access, so it might be good to edit the answer to say that you can only use the OnLoad event in A2007/A2010. The A2007 Help is silent on the real order of events, but I'd assume OnLoad happens after OnOpen, but I don't know which is the more appropriate event.

Comment: I don't understand your further comment. Where did I say anything that implied anything would get saved? I certainly wouldn't want anything saved -- if I did, I wouldn't be doing these kinds of changes in VBA! Indeed, I always recommend avoiding hardwiring criteria/sorting in Access objects! Also, keep in mind that a reports sorting/grouping can override ORDER BY in the report's Recordsource. I have no idea how that interacts with the OrderBy property. It would be something I'd want to test.

Comment: I have edited my answer based on David's feedback. Thanks, David.

Answer (score 0):

[Pivot Charts](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/designing-your-first-pivottable-pivotchart-views-in-access-HA001034580.aspx) are the way to go for more complicated visualization of data.

If you really only want them to select on of the 3 fields, you can have a form where the user selects the field (through a listbox i.e.), open the report through the form and set its source attribute accordingly.

Comment: What do pivot charts have to do with the question?

Comment: It starts with sorting by 3 fields and it ends with being able to use filters etc.